# Android remove item from nested Arraylist given error Concurrent Modification Exception

Tags: android, exception, arraylist, nested

I am new in android. I want to remove item from Arraylist inside Arraylist. But when i removed particular item its given me an error 'ConcurrentModificationException'. So how can i handle it or if any other solution possible then please suggest me to solve this error. i am posting my code.

My code is as follow,

```
for (Item cart : CartItems) {
                if (cart.getIsSub_item() == false) {
                    for (Item list : sclList) {
                        CartItems.remove(list);
                    }
                } else {
                    for (Item i : sclList.get(sub_position).getSub_items()) {
                        if (CartItems.contains(i)) {
                            CartItems.remove(i);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Here is my logcat::

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
            at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.next(ArrayList.java:573)
            at com.njoyful.userapp.Fragments.OrderFragment$RemoveSubItem.doInBackground(OrderFragment.java:800)
            at com.njoyful.userapp.Fragments.OrderFragment$RemoveSubItem.doInBackground(OrderFragment.java:774)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
```

On first line, I am getting error. Thank you.

Comment: post your logcat as well

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterating through a Collection, avoiding ConcurrentModificationException when removing in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/iterating-through-a-collection-avoiding-concurrentmodificationexception-when-re)

Answer (score 0):

[ConcurrentModificationException](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html)

> An ConcurrentModificationException is thrown when a Collection is
>   modified and an existing iterator on the Collection is used to modify
>   the Collection as well.

Seems from the comments that your ArrayList is accessed from the other  method in one thread, by the UI, concurrently with you removing items from it in another thread.

So, why not just wrap both accessors in a

```
synchronized(array_list_name)
{
    // UI access code or item removal code
}
```

**Note** that this might make your UI laggy if removing items takes a long time. If this is the case, consider making a list of all item indexes to be removed, and remove them in a tight synchronized loop after iterating over the whole list.

In another way , Try to using java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList instead of ArrayList  if there are few modifications.

Comment: look into synchronized https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html

Comment: and i cant use java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList. because its very large modification in my code...

Answer (score 0):

Instead Use Iterator to remove item from ArrayList.

```
                Iterator<Items> iter = CartItems.iterator();

                while(iter.hasNext()){

                    if("your condition")
                    {
                        iter.remove();
                    }
                    else{
                         "Your code"}
                }
```